# Setwasmpath error for web-ifc-viewer in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, webassembly, ifc

I have one gatsby.js project to import \*.ifc file and display it in the web browser.

I installed web-ifc-viewer package and copy the 2 files web-ifc.wasm and web-ifc-mt.wasm from its node_modules folder into the component folder, and tried to render sample ifc file but it returns failure.

I also tried to copy 2 wasm files into the public folder, root folder and static folder separately, but got same error.

I created new folder `WebIfcViewer` inside src / components / and add 3 files

```
index.tsx
web-ifc-mt.wasm
web-ifc.wasma
```

Here is the code in the index.tsx.

```
import React, { createRef, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  ResponsiveContext,
  Text,
  Spinner,
  CheckBox
} from "grommet";
import { Color } from 'three';
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import { IfcViewerAPI } from 'web-ifc-viewer';

const WebIfcViwer = () => {
  const size = useContext(ResponsiveContext);
  const ifcContainer = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const [isSnackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = useState(false);
  const [viewer, setViewer] = useState<IfcViewerAPI>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [ifcLoadingErrorMessage, setIfcLoadingErrorMessage] = useState<string>();

  const ifcOnLoad = async (e) => {
    const file = e && e.target && e.target.files && e.target.files[0];
    if (file && viewer) {
      setLoading(true);
      const ifcURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      viewer.IFC.loadIfcUrl(ifcURL);
      setLoading(false)
    }
  };

 

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.getElementById('viewer-container') as HTMLElement;
    const Ifcviewer = new IfcViewerAPI({ container });
    Ifcviewer.axes.setAxes();
    Ifcviewer.grid.setGrid();
    Ifcviewer.IFC.setWasmPath('./');
    setViewer(Ifcviewer);

    window.ondblclick = () => Ifcviewer.IFC.selector.pickIfcItem(true);
    window.onmousemove = () => Ifcviewer.IFC.selector.prePickIfcItem();
    Ifcviewer.clipper.active = true;

  }, []);


  return (
    <Box>
      <Box>
        <input
          type='file'
          id='file'
          accept='.ifc'
          onChange={ifcOnLoad}
        />
        {isLoading && <Spinner />}
        <div style={{ flex: '1 1 auto', minWidth: 0 }}>
          <div id='viewer-container' style={{ position: 'relative', height: '100%', width: '100%' }} />
        </div>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default WebIfcViwer;
```

Here is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "bim-engineering",
  "description": "Production environment for aces applcation",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "author": "tangjingyuanivan@gmail.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-components": "^1.9.6",
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.137.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-credentials": "^3.56.0",
    "@culturehq/add-to-calendar": "^1.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@livechat/widget-react": "^1.3.0",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.4.2",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.1",
    "@types/google.analytics": "^0.0.42",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.13.1",
    "@uploadcare/blocks": "^0.25.4",
    "@uploadcare/react-widget": "^2.4.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.10",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta2",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "dateformat": "^4.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^4.7.0",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-omni-font-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^4.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.14.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-load-script": "^1.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^5.18.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-remote-images": "^3.6.0-alpha.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-resolve-src": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "5.17.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-scroll-indicator": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.14.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.12.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.18.1",
    "gatsby-theme-blog-core": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-theme-landing-page": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.18.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.14.0",
    "gbimage-bridge": "^0.2.2",
    "grommet": "^2.18.0",
    "grommet-icons": "^4.6.2",
    "grommet-theme-hpe": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash.differencewith": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "namor": "^2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.1.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.20",
    "react-range": "^1.8.11",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-search-box": "^2.2.1",
    "react-select": "^4.3.0",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-table": "^7.6.3",
    "react-use-draggable-scroll": "^0.4.0",
    "react-whatsapp-chat-widget": "^1.1.6",
    "rollup": "^3.28.1",
    "sass": "^1.63.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "three": "^0.135.0",
    "uploadcare-widget": "^3.21.2",
    "urijs": "^1.19.11",
    "web-ifc-viewer": "^1.0.134"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.1",
    "cypress": "9.3.1",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby",
    "sass",
    "scss"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "lint": "Get started linting your code with Eslint and stylelint",
    "format": "yarn prettier --write .",
    "start": "yarn develop",
    "serve": "gatsby build && gatsby serve",
    "test": "yarn cypress run",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/stylesheets/application.scss static/css/style.css",
    "postinstall": "yarn patch-package",
    "refresh": "curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/gatsby-starter-sass"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/gatsby-starter-sass/issues"
  }
}
```

Behavior and Results:

When I run this, it displays like this screen [Rendered UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVOQA.png)

If I pick the ifc file called 1.ifc, then it doesn't work and I can see some errors in the browser console.
Here is its content.

```
web-ifc-api.js:5632 wasm streaming compile failed: LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #48 module="a" function="X" error: function import requires a callable

falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

web-ifc-api.js:5623 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #48 module="a" function="X" error: function import requires a callable

web-ifc-api.js:5544 Aborted(LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #48 module="a" function="X" error: function import requires a callable)

RuntimeError: Aborted(LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #48 module="a" function="X" error: function import requires a callable). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.
```

My working Environment:

- Windows 10 pro 64bit
- Visual studio code
- node version 16.15.0

Question:
How can I resolve this wasm path in gatsby project?